# Показать кнопку рядом со всеми полями ввода Android

Tags: android, input

Я пишу android приложение и мне нужно показать рядом со всеми полями ввода (в том числе и в обычных приложениях, и непосредственно в самих браузерах (поле ввода логина пароля на сайтах)) свою кнопку.
Как я могу это реализовать?
Я знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью Assesbillity service, но не могу найти как.

Comment: вы хотите на сайте показывать кнопки из приложения?

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли (и не только на сайтах)

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как мне получить тип полей на сайте, так как это html

Comment: ну можно как вариант искать по id элемента в html, но мне кажется затея вообще не гуд по концепции

Comment: А как получить id самого webview приложения?